# New default search bar focus text color added with Xcode 8.1 update, how to change it?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, tvos

### Question:

How do I set the "focused" state of a UISearchBar text color from the default white, to black?

*I created the search bar programmatically, see end of post for that code.*

### Description:

Previously I was using this extension to set the search bar color:

```
public extension UISearchBar {

    public func setTextColor(color: UIColor) {
        let svs = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
        guard let tf = (svs.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField else { return }
        tf.textColor = color
    }

}
```

Which worked great and is still working. However, search bars seem to be "focusable" in a sense. If they are focused, then the text color switches to white (which is the same as the search bar background color) making the text invisible.

Under my search bar I have a table view, where I populate it with data regarding what the person was searching.

When I focus any of the table cells, the UISearchBar text color goes to the black I had originally specified.

### Programmatically created SearchBar

Called in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func configueSearchController() -> UIViewController {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil)
        guard let searchResultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SearchViewController.storyboardIdentifier) as? SearchViewController else {
            fatalError("Unable to instatiate a SearchResultViewController from the storyboard.")
        }

        /*
         Create a UISearchController, passing the `searchResultsController` to
         use to display search results.
         */

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. Gastric Bypass)", comment: "")
        searchController.view.backgroundColor = Constants.Color.backgroundcolor
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = Constants.Color.backgroundcolor
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = Constants.Color.backgroundColorSearch
        searchController.searchBar.setTextColor(color: .black)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        //searchResultsController.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        // Contain the `UISearchController` in a `UISearchContainerViewController`.
        let searchContainer: UISearchContainerViewController = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)

        // Finally contain the `UISearchContainerViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.
        let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchContainer)
        searchNavigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        searchNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = Constants.Color.backgroundcolor
        searchNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = "Search"
        return searchNavigationController

    }
```

Comment: you can use appearance property to obtain the desired effect...

Comment: @sargeras sorry forgot to add the tvOS tag. Appearance property doesn't exist in tvOS.

Comment: then you would have to update it's color using it's delegate methods, although appearance is available for tvOS 9.0+, are you supporting any previous versions? I don't think you are as even `UISearchContainerViewController` is available on tvOS 9.0+

Comment: @sargeras I'm confused. What delegate methods are you referring to? If there was an appearance method I would have used it by now. I'm only able to modify the keyboardAppearance.

I'm using UISearchContainerViewController in the example above.

Comment: I am talking about `UISearchBarDelegate` delegate to `UISearchController`'s searchBar...

Comment: `UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red` should be working for you